# como imprimir una consulta de MySQL por consola con caracteres UTF8

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, consola, utf-8

debo de sacar una información de MySQL (reportes de ciudades de Colombia) entonces hago la siguiente consulta:

```
select id, name, slug, latitude, longitude, region_id, province_id, district_id from places;
```

La consulta funciona y me arroja todos los resultados

El problema es que todas las consultas salen con cosas como: �����

Nari�o

Mi pregunta puntual es: Es posible visualizar desde consola la consulta con tildes y ñ????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arranca el cliente indicándole el charset por defecto

```
mysql --default-character-set=utf8
```

O, para versión con implementación completa de UTF

```
mysql --default-character-set=utf8mb4
```

Que incluso puede definirse por defecto en la configuración (`/etc/mysql/my.cnf` en Linux):

```
[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8
```

Cuando estés en la nueva sesión en consola aplicando alguno de estos cambios, revisa que todo esté en UTF8 con

```
show variables like '%char%';
```

Revisa en qué codificación están tus datos y tu tabla. Si están en latin1, tienes que hacer este ajuste pero usando `latin1`.

(Respuesta generada a partir de [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6788223/236345))

Comment: Muchichichichisissmas Gracias me funcionó perfectamente :)